# Interrupt react lifecycle in the constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I am trying to interrupt the lifecycle of a react component if a condition is not met, on the constructor. Still, it goes on to render.

Basically, what i want to do is if a user is not logged in, redirect. However it goes into the render part.

Can i do this straight in the constructor, like stop whatever is coming afterwards, or do i have to go into component will mount or something?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentWIllMount should do the trick.

You can set up your state to to contain a user or isAuth property and conditionally render the path or component the user wants to access depending on if the state you're expecting exists or is not an empty string.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I thought i could avoid the conditional render, the setting of all state variables, the declaring of functions, etc to be read if i could somehow interrupt everything if there was no user

Comment: You probably can, but it seems like any alternative route has the potential to be a painful one, or result in bad UI. You could probably interrupt the route rendering during the route stage, but it also involves conditional rendering and state. ;(

Comment: I am going to mark as right answer since it seems to be that way, but what I will do instead is make the conditional in the parent of the component, and if the user is not logged in, not call the component at all and redirect. Thanks